# Regiser JacksonJsonProvider in Websphere liberty profile

Tags: jackson, jax-rs, websphere-liberty

I am trying to call a REST service from an EJB hoping to utilize Jackson's

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

The following does the trick in wlp v8.5.5.9

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(JacksonJsonProvider.class);
```

The same code produces a `NullPointerException` in the wlp v16.0.0.2

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.tl.ThreadLocalProviders.getContextResolver(ThreadLocalProviders.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.locateMapper(JacksonJsonProvider.java:634)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:413)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBodyReader(JAXRSUtils.java:1356)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.doReadEntity(ResponseImpl.java:438)
    ... 98 more
```

I have found a [discussions](https://m.ibm.com/https/developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/275628/liberty-jax-rs-20-client-unmarshalling-not-working.html?wirelessshow=2) triggered by the same problems in v8.5.5.9, but I am not sure how it could help me. As I noted I have no troubles with the code in the v8.5.5.9

Another [discussion](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/253349/was-liberty-beta-2016-01-does-not-use-deployed-jac.html) was related to the Jackson v2.x. Initially I used Jackson v1.9.13, but I have tried to switch to the newest Jeckson 2.8.0 version and apply the offered solution. The same outcome: application works in wlp 8.5.5.9 and produces the same error in v16.0.0.2.

Any ideas?

**Update:**
the problem could be avoided by extending the JacksonJsonProvider class and explicitly providing object mapper

```
public class MyJacksonJsonProvider extends JacksonJsonProvider {

        public MyJacksonJsonProvider() {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.setVisibilityChecker(objectMapper.getVisibilityChecker().withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY));
            objectMapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
            setMapper(objectMapper);
       }

}
```

and then registering it in the client

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(MyJacksonJsonProvider.class);
```

However it would be nice to understand if it is a bug or a feature.

Comment: I suspect it is a bug. The latest beta driver does not exhibit this behavior (I've raised it and we're chasing). FWIW, we just hit it with one of our apps, too.

Comment: The most recent beta driver seems not to have this issue for our application. True for you as well?

Comment: @ebullient, thanks for the note. I will give it a try and let you know. However could you please tell what driver did you mean?