# WELD-001318: Ambigous dependency when using JaxbJsonProvider and JsonProvider on WAS Liberty

Tags: json, jaxb, websphere-liberty, weld

I am running a server under WebSphere Application Server (17.0.0.1/wlp-1.0.16.cl170120170227-0220) and have added the changes recommended in this post ([How to change Jackson version in JAX-RS app (WebSphere Liberty)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39388651/how-to-change-jackson-version-in-jax-rs-app-websphere-liberty/39403224)) for upgrading the level of Jackson in WAS Liberty.  I am using Postman to test my server.  When I submit a GET request for an object, it completes successfully.  (After adding this change, my server can return my objects in either XML or JSON.). However, I am now seeing these messages in the server console when my server builds the Response object.

[INFO    ] FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "org.jboss.weld.exceptions.AmbiguousResolutionException: WELD-001318: Cannot resolve an ambiguous dependency between: 
  - Managed Bean [class com.ibm.zss.boundary.JaxbJsonProvider] with qualifiers [@Any @Default],
  - Managed Bean [class com.ibm.zss.boundary.JsonProvider] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.cdi.component.JaxRsFactoryImplicitBeanCDICustomizer 425" at ffdc_17.06.13_15.59.57.0.log

com.ibm.zss.boundary.JaxbJsonProvider and com.ibm.zss.boundary.JsonProvider are the classes I added based on the instructions from the previous post.

I also updated my server.xml to include:

```
    <feature>jsonp-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jaxrs-2.0</feature>
```

I've been searching for solutions for handling a WELD ambiguousResolutionException, but most of them address issues with classes where the developer has control over what is being injected.  So, I don't know if I have any control over the code that I need to change for this problem.

For completeness, here are the classes which I added to my application:

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider;

@Provider
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JaxbJsonProvider extends JacksonJaxbJsonProvider {

}

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider;


@Provider
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JsonProvider extends JacksonJsonProvider  {
  public JsonProvider() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
       objectMapper.setVisibility(objectMapper.getVisibilityChecker().withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY));
setMapper(objectMapper);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you either mark it an @Specializes or an @Alternative with low @Priority, depending on whether you want it to be used for injection points?

Comment: I marked both classes with @Alternative and it worked.  I don't understand why.  From the research I had done, it didn't seem that these were the classes which needed to be annotated.  Thank you.